# AutoCompleteCustomSource, AutoCompleteMode, and AutoCompleteSource

Tags: c#, windows

I am using AutoCompleteCustomSource, AutoCompleteMode, and AutoCompleteSource properties to create a TextBox that automatically completes input strings. But it  compares the prefix being entered in textbox to the prefixes of all strings in a maintained source.

But I dont want to compare the prefix. I want to compare the suffix of all the string.

Below is my code snippet

```
    /* Event triggered on text change */
    private void tbSelectedValue_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> drawingList = new List<string>();
        drawingList=ReadDrawingNames(tbSelectedValue.Text);
        if (drawingList!=null && drawingList.Count > 0) {
           this.tbSelectedValue.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(drawingList.ToArray());
        }       
    }

    /* Function to get suggestions for Auto complete  */
    public List<string> ReadDrawingNames(string tbSelectvalueText)
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        List<string> drawingFileName = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            dt = PIDDBUtilities.GetSQLData(string.Format("SELECT [DrawingName] FROM [SynchroniseDetails] where [DrawingName] like '%{0}%'",tbSelectvalueText), PIDDBTYPE.REPORTSDB);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (!drawingFileName.Contains(row["DrawingName"].ToString()))
                    drawingFileName.Add(row["DrawingName"].ToString());
            }
            return drawingFileName;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errormsg = ex.Message;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**AutoCompleteCustomSource** automatically completes input strings by comparing the prefix being entered to the prefixes of all strings in a maintained source.[See msdn for more details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletecustomsource(v=vs.110).aspx). It's quite illogical that you want to compare the suffix of all the string. Kindly share further details that what do you want to achieve?